# Android Studio not recognising some packages

Tags: android, android-studio, package

In my project I have a package com.bi.bio, and within it are packages like "base", "data", "events", "auth" etc. When I try to add my activities to the manifest from, say, "auth", the "auth" package is not recognised - with message "class referenced not found in project or libraries".
Similarly some other packages like "events" are not recognised, while some packages, say "base", are getting recognised.

This image shows my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

This image shows the error while trying to add an Activity in a package, in manifest:

[image: Manifest error]

What do I do to make Android Studio recognise all my packages.

Comment: Share a screenshot of your problem

Comment: @Rahil, Added images in question.

Comment: Have you tried entering the full name (with package) of activity ?

Comment: Actually I had forgotten to set the package name of my Activity correctly after copying it from another module. Working after correcting it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

1. Rebuilding the project

   **Build -> Rebuild**
2. Invalidate cache.

   **File -> Invalidate cache and restart**

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest file Enter PackageName Like this

```
package="com.bi.bio"
```

Like this, you can add activity in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, had forgotten to set the package name properly in the Activity concerned, after copying the Activity from another module.

Worked after correcting the package name in my Activity.